# has_many association with multiple foreign keys to the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have two tables, `Teams` and `Games`. I am trying to set up the associations for these tables but running into some issues. Here is my `Game` model with it's associations:

```
# Game Model

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_team, class_name: "Team"
  belongs_to :away_team, class_name: "Team"
  belongs_to :winning_team, class_name: "Team"
end
```

I may be overthinking this but I'm not sure how to set up my `Team` model to have_many Games.

With a simple `has_many :games` in my Team model, my tests return the following error:

```
Team Associations should have many games
     Failure/Error: it { should have_many(:games) }
       Expected Team to have a has_many association called games (Game does not have a team_id foreign key.)
```

I see that it's looking for `team_id` for `Game`, and since there's no `team_id` it errors. But in my `Game` table I have three foreign keys referencing the same class. So would I need to create a `has_many` for each `home_team`, `away_team` and `winning_team`?

Comment: A question about database design should NEVER include an ORM or application software in it. That is not the right tool for database design. EVER! The real database design would have three tables, Game with details about the game, team with details about the team and TeamGAme as a junction table for the many to many association.

Comment: @HLGEM this didn't seem to be a question about database design, the database is already set up in a functional way.  The question is can you glom all three associations together with one has_many reference or not.  Also, why do you suggest a join table?  The details about the Game in this case are the two teams that played, seems like a join table would be overkill.  Perhaps I'm missing something?  I think the database design is correct.

Comment: @GoGoCarl Thanks, I was starting to doubt my methods. And yes, I'm looking for a way to either handle a has_many with a single line, or as three individual has_many lines.

Comment: @mikeymurph77 see answer below.  Pretty sure that (a) it's not possible with a single has_many, but (b) for your situation, you probably don't want that anyway.  I'm making presumptions based on the names of the models and meaning behind the words, but I would presume that the winning team of any game would be either the home team or winning team, and a potential game method would return duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need something like:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'home_team_id'
  has_many :away_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'away_team_id'

  # This seems like a separate thing to me...
  has_many :winning_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'winning_team_id'

  # Do not include winning games, since it would already be included
  def games
    self.home_games.to_a + self.away_games.to_a
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly and gets my tests to pass. Much appreciated.